# Passing a global ObservableList between 2 classes

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question. How can i pass the same reference of one ObservableList between two classes? I need to add an Element from my SimultanTestController to the List in FXMLDocumentController.

My Code (FXMLDocumentController):

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {   

    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Stage options = new Stage();
    Stage selectTest = new Stage();

    ObservableList<DefaultTestInterface> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public ObservableList<DefaultTestInterface> getList() {
        return items;
        }

    @FXML
    private ListView ItemList;
    @FXML
    public Button btn_globalOptions;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_add;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_delete;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_moveUP;
    @FXML
    private Button btn_moveDOWN;

    public void getPrimaryStage(Stage stage){
        this.primaryStage=stage;
    }
```

My Code (SimultanTestController):

```
public class SimultanTestController implements Initializable {

ObservableList<DefaultTestInterface> items = (new FXMLDocumentController()).getList();

@FXML
Button btn_ok;

    public void addTest(ActionEvent event){
           for( int x = 0 ; x < items.size() ; x++ ) { // start from index 0
        System.out.println("Item" +items.get(x));
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       btn_ok.setOnAction(this::addTest);
    }
}
```

So you see, i have one Method: getList

and this method is called in SimultanTestController and i try to parse the value of getList to the ObservableList in SimultanTestController.
After that, i want to to add an element to the ObservableList in FXMLDocumentController from SimultanTestController. But i dont get the same list in both classes ...

Thank you for help!

I load my FXML-Files in this class:
First i create all new stages for my FXML-Files and have 3 ObservableList with the FXML-File-Names, the window-titel and all the stages. Then i load all stages with my for-loop. (By the way, is this a good solution?)

My window opening way: Main-->SelectTest-->SimultanTest

public class SelectTestController implements Initializable {

```
ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList();

Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
Stage simultan = new Stage();
Stage audioLoop = new Stage();
Stage cpu = new Stage();
Stage driversCD = new Stage();
Stage driversHD = new Stage();
Stage driversFD = new Stage();
Stage externalProgramm = new Stage();
Stage graphics = new Stage();
Stage interactive = new Stage();
Stage mainboard = new Stage();
Stage memorySPD = new Stage();
Stage memory = new Stage();
Stage network = new Stage();
Stage ports = new Stage();
Stage reboot = new Stage();
Stage signal = new Stage();
Stage userMessage = new Stage();

@FXML
private ListView lv_selectTest;
@FXML
private Button btn_choose;
@FXML
private Label test;

public void getPrimaryStage(Stage stage){
    this.primaryStage=stage;
}

ObservableList<Stage> stages =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> fxml =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ObservableList<String> stageTitel =FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initWindows(){
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<=stages.size();i++){
        Window parent = primaryStage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml.get(i)));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stages.get(i).initOwner(parent);
        stages.get(i).initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stages.get(i).setTitle(stageTitel.get(i));
        stages.get(i).setScene(scene);
        stages.get(i).setResizable(false);
        stages.get(i).setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        }
    }catch (IOException|IllegalStateException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

I tried to get the controller of the FXML-Loader and this works. I get the value from JavaFX-Start methode and parse it to FXMLDocumentController. Now i have a var with the controller instance in my FXMLDocumentConroller. But i am not able to get the value in SimultanTest ot add something to the ObservableList items. I tired per new Instance() and setter+getter... I dont know why i dont get it...

It would be very nice if someone could give me an example based of my code ... You see i worked for my solution but im not getting further...

Comment: The controllers are created by their respective `FXMLLoader`s. Creating one by hand (as you do with `newFXMLDocumentController()` in your `SimultanTestController`) is no use to you, as you really need a reference to the controller created by the `FXMLLoader`. What is the relationship between these two controllers? Where are their corresponding FXML files loaded?

Comment: I have added additional Informations for you. Sry this is my first Question on StackOverflow ...

Comment: "I have a question", "You see i worked ..", "Thank you for help", "I don't know why i don't get it" are all question irrelevant fluff that doesn't belong in a question (read the help tour it clearly states no distractions, no chit-chat. Removing those, apart from making the post more easy to read,  will also have the positive side effect immediately drop the number of spelling errors in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found an own solution for my Problem. I dont get the Controller of FXMLMain, but i solved it with an Singelton Class which stores the ObservableList items.

Now i can set Items from every class and can show them in ListView in FXMLDocumentController. If some one have the same Problem, connect me for a solution.

Thanks for help @ James_D